# Convert from 1280x720 to UIView dimensions

Tags: xcode, ios6, uikit, core-graphics

I have an app that finds QR finder marks from the AVCaptureDevice sample buffer delegate. Now I am trying to put boxes on the screen to cover the QR marks. However, I am having trouble converting between 1280x720 pixel resolution and the cameraView size.

I'm trying to write a method that converts a CGRect based on these parameters (and the fact that the view coordinate system is upside-down), but it won't work. It might have something to do with the orientation of the camera device as well. Here is my code for the converting method:

```
-(CGRect) convertRect:(CGRect) oldRect From90DegreeRotatedCameraSize1280x720ToUIViewSize:(CGSize) viewSize
{
//remember that we are using a gravity of resize aspect fill

double xScale = viewSize.width / 720;
double yScale = viewSize.height / 1280;

if (xScale < yScale)
    return CGRectMake(oldRect.origin.x * xScale, viewSize.height - oldRect.origin.y * xScale, oldRect.size.height * xScale, oldRect.size.width * xScale);
else
    return CGRectMake(oldRect.origin.x * yScale, viewSize.height - oldRect.origin.y * yScale, oldRect.size.height * yScale, oldRect.size.width * yScale);
}
```

Anyone got an elegant to solution to this relatively simple spacial coordinate problem?

EDIT -

I did a NSLog of the connection video orientation and it turns out that it never changes from 1 (which I think is enum'ed to portrait orientation.) From this, it should be easier to find a solution because the coordinates do not change in different orientations.

Any ideas, coder community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

When iOS fills a view, it centers it so that the both sides are cut off. In order to transition between view coordinates, you need to scale and THEN translate in the direction that was cut off:

```
            return CGRectMake(oldRect.origin.x * xScale, oldRect.origin.y * xScale - (1280 * xScale - viewSize.height) / 2, oldRect.size.height * xScale, oldRect.size.width * yScale);
```